# How to make user email non-required upon registration in drupal 7?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, registration

How to make user email non-required (optional) upon registration in drupal 7?

Comment: And when you ask for a password reset link then what?

Comment: I am going to use only third-party providers to login/register like facebook, twitter, google etc. No need for the password reset link.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to make a custom module. It's really similar to sharedemail.

```
<?php
function noemail_form_user_register_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  noemail_form_user_account_form_alter($form, $form_state, $form_id);
}
function noemail_form_user_profile_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  noemail_form_user_account_form_alter($form, $form_state, $form_id);
}
function noemail_form_user_account_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if (is_array($form['#validate'])) {
    $key = array_search( 'user_account_form_validate', $form['#validate'], TRUE );
    if ( $key !== FALSE ) {
      $form['#validate'][$key] = 'noemail_account_form_validate';
    }
  }
    $form['account']['mail']['#required'] = FALSE;
}
function noemail_account_form_validate($form, &$form_state) {
    $form['account']['mail']['#needs_validation'] = false;
}
```

and the install file in case it's key

```
<?php
function sharedemail_install() {
  db_query("UPDATE {system} SET weight = -99 WHERE name = 'noemail'");
}
```

Hope this helps, wow this is a really old thread. Oh and note this is for d7

Answer (score 1):

You can't really change another validation hook.

What you could try to do is build your own validation and on that form's validation (['#validate']) array only instantiate your own validation hook.

Answer (score 1):

There is a optional mail module that makes the email field optional in user registration. Visit https://www.drupal.org/project/optional_mail ,
I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could override the [#required setting](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html#required) on the field using the [Form API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html) inside of a custom module with a [hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) implementation.

Comment: Tried that. But is not enough. There is a validation that needs to be overridden. I don't know how to do that.